# ReflectionException Controller does not exist error in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I make Controller in App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php

I use route following code

```
$app->get('api/article','App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@index');
```

But I can't call Controller! **Controller does not exist.....** error occur.
How can solve?
 [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to specify the namespace relative to `App\Http\Controllers`. So it would be like this:

```
$app->get('api/article','ArticleController@index');
```

Also, for future reference, if your controller is in a "deeper" namespace, the same rule applies. So, if your `ArticlesController` was in `App\Http\Controllers\API\ArticleController`, you would just need to do this:

```
$app->get('api/article', 'API\ArticleController@index');
```

> It is very important to note that we did not need to specify the full controller namespace when defining the controller route. We only defined the portion of the class name that comes after the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace "root". By default, the `bootstrap/app.php` file will load the routes.php file within a route group containing the root controller namespace.
>
> If you choose to nest or organize your controllers using PHP namespaces deeper into the `App\Http\Controllers directory`, simply use the specific class name relative to the `App\Http\Controllers root namespace`. So, if your full controller class is `App\Http\Controllers\Photos\AdminController`, you would register a route like so:
>
> `$app->get('foo', 'Photos\AdminController@method');`

Source: http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/controllers#basic-controllers